# Help Tracking Win Messages

Tags: disassembly

I'm new to reverse engineering, have been using olly and x64_dbg. I've ,to a degree, successfully reverse engineered and understood functions and parts of code of a couple applications. I cannot READ Asm or spot data structures quite yet. I recently tried peeking at a disassembled code of a new PE and it's obfuscated. So it's far over my head at this point but I continued to dig in. I came across a popup dialog created/initiated by the `User32.CreateWindowExA`  function. Due to anti debugging code I cannot place any breakpoints in the actual executable.... well certain memory locations of the exe and dlls can have breakpoints. Anyway I narrowed things down to a `DispatchMessageA` function being called then the `CreateWindowExA` function. I can't find out what happens between the two or find the GetMessage funct. I believe I know the message being sent but my question is, how do I find the receiving message function for the appropriate message sent out. Let's say 3 different messages can be sent out how do I find out who collects them?

Answer (score 2):

As it stands the query is too broad

to capture all the messages that are sent Via GetMessageX to a certain process A conditional log  breakpoint similar to this can be employed

**OS xpsp3 using windbg and `Ken Johnsons` sdbgext windbg extension**

Demo Result

**finding index of GetMessage**

```
0:000> uf USER32!NtUserGetMessage
USER32!NtUserGetMessage:
7e4191b2 b8a5110000      mov     eax,11A5h
7e4191b7 ba0003fe7f      mov     edx,offset SharedUserData!SystemCallStub (7ffe0300)
7e4191bc ff12            call    dword ptr [edx]
7e4191be c21000          ret     10h
```

**to know how many step over is required**

```
0:000> uf ntdll!KiFastSystemCall
ntdll!KiFastSystemCall:
7c90e510 8bd4            mov     edx,esp
7c90e512 0f34            sysenter
7c90e514 c3              ret
```

**setting a conditional log breakpoint using index and number of step overs**

```
0:000> bp ntdll!KiFastSystemCall ".if(@eax == 11a5) {r $t0 = poi(@esp+8);p 2 \"!usermsg @$t0;g\";} .else {gc}"
```

**confirming the breakpoint**

```
0:000> .bpcmds
bp0 0x7c90e510  ".if(@eax == 11a5) {r $t0 = poi(@esp+8);p 2 \"!usermsg @$t0;g\";} .else {gc}";
```

**executing**

```
0:000> g
```

**log the voluminous spew to be  parsed later **

```
eax=000011a5 ebx=00000000 ecx=00000000 edx=0007fde0 esi=0007fee8 edi=01014018
eip=7c90e512 esp=0007fde0 ebp=0007fdfc iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000246
ntdll!KiFastSystemCall+0x2:
7c90e512 0f34            sysenter
hwnd:
Window    000a01d6
Name      C
Class     Button
WndProc   00000000
Style     WS_OVERLAPPED 
ExStyle   WS_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY WS_EX_LEFT WS_EX_LTRREADING WS_EX_RIGHTSCROLLBAR 
HInstance 01000000
ParentWnd 001200e0
Id        00000088
UserData  00000000
Unicode   TRUE
ThreadId  00000be8
ProcessId 00000be0
Message: WM_PAINT
wParam: 0
lParam: 0
Time: 5bd026
pt: (1021, 413)
eax=000011a5 ebx=00000000 ecx=00000000 edx=0007fde0 esi=0007fee8 edi=01014018
eip=7c90e512 esp=0007fde0 ebp=0007fdfc iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000246
ntdll!KiFastSystemCall+0x2:
7c90e512 0f34            sysenter
hwnd:
Window    00080186
Name      /
Class     Button
WndProc   00000000
Style     WS_OVERLAPPED 
ExStyle   WS_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY WS_EX_LEFT WS_EX_LTRREADING WS_EX_RIGHTSCROLLBAR 
HInstance 01000000
ParentWnd 001200e0
Id        0000005a
UserData  00000000
Unicode   TRUE
ThreadId  00000be8
ProcessId 00000be0
Message: WM_PAINT
wParam: 0
lParam: 0
Time: 5bd14f
pt: (1021, 413)
eax=000011a5 ebx=00000000 ecx=00000000 edx=0007fde0 esi=0007fee8 edi=01014018
eip=7c90e512 esp=0007fde0 ebp=0007fdfc iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000246
ntdll!KiFastSystemCall+0x2:
7c90e512 0f34            sysenter
hwnd:
Window    000a0160
Name      *
Class     Button
WndProc   00000000
Style     WS_OVERLAPPED 
ExStyle   WS_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY WS_EX_LEFT WS_EX_LTRREADING WS_EX_RIGHTSCROLLBAR 
HInstance 01000000
ParentWnd 001200e0
Id        0000005b
UserData  00000000
Unicode   TRUE
ThreadId  00000be8
ProcessId 00000be0
Message: WM_PAINT
wParam: 0
lParam: 0
Time: 5bd249
pt: (1021, 413)
eax=000011a5 ebx=00000000 ecx=00000000 edx=0007fde0 esi=0007fee8 edi=01014018
eip=7c90e512 esp=0007fde0 ebp=0007fdfc iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000246
ntdll!KiFastSystemCall+0x2:
7c90e512 0f34            sysenter
```

Comment: Wow thanks. It appears I have a lot to learn but not being able to see how deep the rabbit hole gets only makes me more excited. X64_dbg does not have conditional breakpoints yet. Their hardware breakpoints don't reliably work yet. It's a great program I look forward to its future but I'll give windgb a look at and hopefully things go well. Thanks for the advice. I plan to start reading.       practical reverse engineering.      this weekend. Hopefully that'll help with the obfuscation.

Comment: @TurtleMan: Please, don't forget to tick the answer as correct ! And possibly vote for it if you think it deserve it. The principle of Stack-Exchange websites is based on the hypothesis that every should follow these simples rules. If nobody do it, it won't be possible to distinguish good answers from gibberish.